# ¿Cómo utilizar una API con asp.net entity framework mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Busco saber como utilizar una api con asp.net entity framework mvc, soy nuevo programando y he visto que es de muy común y de utililidad el uso de apis hoy en día, me parece interesante la existencia de una api de pokemon https://pokeapi.co/ y me gustaría usarla para saber como trabajar con ella y con APIS en general, pero no encuentro una fuente de como puedo implementar su uso en asp.net entity framework mvc.

Comment: Este workshop te ayudará: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY y en mi blog tengo algunos posts del tema http://fredyfx.com/blog

Comment: @RichardVíquezPérez bájale un poco a tu comentario, orienta al usuario a caer en cuenta que hizo mal la pregunta, no a ser sarcástico o antipático, por favor. ...... Ahora Fran , Deberías consultar como consumir e implementar una API desde asp.net Suponiendo que tienes un conocimiento en este lenguaje.

Comment: Hola @Fran, mírate este artículo[Cómo crear un cliente C# para un Web API de ASP.NET MVC](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/10/29/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-cliente-c-para-un-web-api-de-aspnet-core-iii) , y luego cuando hayas intentado programar algo de código, reformula la pregunta, indicando en código donde has tenido problemas.

Comment: Gracias Fredy, Rafael, encontré este instructivo [http://vbpuntonet.blogspot.com/2018/06/api-rest-consumiendo-un-api-rest-en-c.html], donde dicen como hacerlo paso a paso, ahora tengo un inconveniente para deserializar de json a list<>, la informacion que recibe mi aplicación desde el api.